# Handling '-' with boost.program_options

Tags: c++, boost, cat, boost-program-options

Before you say OVERKILL, I don't care.

How can I make Boost.program_options handle the required `cat` option `-`?

I have

```
// visible
po::options_description options("Options");
options.add_options()("-u", po::value<bool>(), "Write bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.");

po::positional_options_description file_options;
file_options.add("file", -1);

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(options).positional(file_options).run(), vm);
po::notify(vm);

bool immediate = false;
if(vm.count("-u"))
  immediate = true;
if(vm.count("file"))
  support::print(vm["file"].as<vector<string>>());
```

which throws an exception when I run `cat - - -`:

> unrecognised option '-'

I want it to see `-` as a positional argument, and I need it in the correct order in the full file list. How could I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have a half fix. I needed

```
po::options_description options("Options");
options.add_options()("-u", po::value<bool>(), "Write bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.")
                    ("file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "input file");

po::positional_options_description file_options;
file_options.add("file", -1);
```

Problem is, I seem to only get 2 of the three `-` when I output the arguments:

```
if(vm.count("file"))
  support::print(vm["file"].as<vector<string>>());
```

where support::print nicely handles the vector and stuff.

Comment: Boost.PO has its own (sort of limited) syntax of options. Probably you can use Boost.PO for the syntax you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the named program option that is positional, in your case it is `file`

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::vector<std::string> input;
    po::options_description options("Options");
    options.add_options()
        ("-u", po::value<bool>(), "Write bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.")
        ("file", po::value(&input), "input")
        ;

    po::positional_options_description file_options;
    file_options.add("file", -1);

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(options).positional(file_options).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    bool immediate = false;
    if(vm.count("-u"))
        immediate = true;
    BOOST_FOREACH( const auto& i, input ) {
        std::cout << "file: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's a [coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2adc03f6a415730af30f31d2d77d56ab-1b2e912b8f4a28f296b926d355b0e4c3) and the output if you don't want to click through

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -pthread main.cpp -lboost_program_options && ./a.out - - -
file: -
file: -
file: -
```

---

If you only see 2 of 3 positional arguments, it's likely because `argv[0]` is by convention the program name, and is therefore not considered for argument parsing. This can be seen in the source code for the `basic_command_line_parser` template

```
 37     template<class charT>
 38     basic_command_line_parser<charT>::
 39     basic_command_line_parser(int argc, const charT* const argv[])
 40     : detail::cmdline(
 41         // Explicit template arguments are required by gcc 3.3.1 
 42         // (at least mingw version), and do no harm on other compilers.
 43         to_internal(detail::make_vector<charT, const charT* const*>(argv+1, argv+argc+!argc)))
 44     {}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already figured that part out. It seems my meddling with argv is not what boost.program_options expected, and it ignored the first argv, although I removed argv[0].

Comment: @rubenvb you should probably tag the question as [tag:windows] or some such then, what does your `argv` look like?